# Echoing empty array values returns "undefined index" error

Tags: php, html, arrays

I think this is a relatively simple question to answer. Here is the basic layout of what I want to do.

I have an array

```
$polarity_array
```

Values of the array are HTML  tags which display an image.

But some values of these arrays are empty, because I performed a function which UNSETS any array value equal to "No mod in this slot" (A dropdown box selection in a form when they submit something)

I then have a heredoc, echoing my HTML page which contains the values of these arrays like such:

```
{$polarity_array['image_polarity1']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity2']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity3']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity4']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity5']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity6']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity7']}
{$polarity_array['image_polarity8']}
```

But since some values AREN'T set (and the unset values depend on what the user submitted initially), I get "undefined index" errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
    <?php

include_once 'header.php';
require_once 'login_builds.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

//Connect to server

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

//Select the database for build-related pages

mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

//Retrieve page variables from GET array for inital querying, decode them

$buildname = $_GET['buildname'];
$author = $_GET['author'];
$pageitem = sanitizeString(urldecode($buildname));
$pageauthor = sanitizeString(urldecode($author));

//Set variables for array query and object image retrieval

$query_info = "SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE buildname='$pageitem' AND author='$pageauthor'";

$info_result = mysql_query($query_info);
$info_array = mysql_fetch_array($info_result);

//Remove entries with no mod, and no polarity
/*
foreach($info_array as $key => $string)
{
    if($string == "n" || $string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        unset($info_array[$key]);
    }
}
*/

$page_id = $info_array['id'];
$page_author = $info_array['author'];
$page_buildname = $info_array['buildname'];
$page_weapon = $info_array['weapon'];
$page_mod1 = $info_array['mod1'];
$page_mod2 = $info_array['mod2'];
$page_mod3 = $info_array['mod3'];
$page_mod4 = $info_array['mod4'];
$page_mod5 = $info_array['mod5'];
$page_mod6 = $info_array['mod6'];
$page_mod7 = $info_array['mod7'];
$page_mod8 = $info_array['mod8'];
$page_polarity1 = $info_array['polarity1'];
$page_polarity2 = $info_array['polarity2'];
$page_polarity3 = $info_array['polarity3'];
$page_polarity4 = $info_array['polarity4'];
$page_polarity5 = $info_array['polarity5'];
$page_polarity6 = $info_array['polarity6'];
$page_polarity7 = $info_array['polarity7'];
$page_polarity8 = $info_array['polarity8'];
$page_category = $info_array['category'];
$page_description = $info_array['description'];
$page_date = $info_array['date'];
$page_hidden = $info_array['hidden'];

//Check if the accessing user is the same as the page creator. If not, check if page is hidden. If page is hidden, redirect to index.php.

if($_SESSION['username'] != $page_author)
{
    if($page_hidden == y)
    {
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

//Retrieve Page Main Image

$page_main_image = convertImageMainPageWeapon($page_weapon);

//Set up mod and polarity associative arrays


$mod_array = array(

"image_mod1" =>     "$page_mod1",
"image_mod2" =>     "$page_mod2",
"image_mod3" =>     "$page_mod3",
"image_mod4" =>     "$page_mod4",
"image_mod5" =>     "$page_mod5",
"image_mod6" =>     "$page_mod6",
"image_mod7" =>     "$page_mod7",
"image_mod8" =>     "$page_mod8"

);

$polarity_array = array(

"image_polarity1" => "$page_polarity1",
"image_polarity2" => "$page_polarity2",
"image_polarity3" => "$page_polarity3",
"image_polarity4" => "$page_polarity4",
"image_polarity5" => "$page_polarity5",
"image_polarity6" => "$page_polarity6",
"image_polarity7" => "$page_polarity7",
"image_polarity8" => "$page_polarity8"

);

foreach($mod_array as $key => $string)
{
    if($string == "No mod in this slot")
    {
        unset($mod_array[$key]);
    }
}

foreach($polarity_array as $key => $string)
{
    if($string == "n")
    {
        unset($polarity_array[$key]);
    }
}

foreach($mod_array as &$string)
{
    if($string != "")
    {
    $string = convertImageMod($string);
    }
}

foreach($polarity_array as &$string)
{
    if($string != "")
    {
    $string = convertImagePolarity($string);
    }
}



echo<<<_END

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Weapon Build Creator</title>

<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body style="background-image: url('images/bg.jpg')">

<div id="form" style="form">
<div class="newsdiv">
    <br />
    <p class="title">$page_buildname <br />
    (ID: $page_id)</p>
    <p class="regular_text">Author: $page_author<br />
    Weapon: $page_weapon</p>
    <img class="center_image" src="$page_main_image"></img><br />
    <p class="mod_text"> MODS AND POLARITIES</p>
    <p class="regular_text"></p>

<?php

    for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i])) {
        echo $polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i];
    } else {
        echo "This slot is empty.";
    }
}

?>

    <p class="regular_text"> Description:</p>
    <div class="description_text_div"> &nbsp;$page_description<br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <p class="regular_text">*comment section currently disabled for beta testing*</p>
    </div>
    <form action = "authenticate.php" class="regular_text" method="post">
        <div class="auto-style1">
            <p class="warning_text">
            <br />
        <br /></p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>

_END;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check if the index exists, like this:

```
if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity1'])) {
    echo $polarity_array['image_polarity1'];
} else {
    echo "This slot is empty.";
}
```

I'm not sure what those curly brackets in your example mean, though.

Even better, use array to loop through the items:

```
for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i])) {
        echo $polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i];
    } else {
        echo "This slot is empty.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Will these commands run in my HTML document surrounded by heredoc constructs? Or do i have to issue each command separately

Comment: It will not work in your heredoc. Replace echo with `$polarity_array['image_polarity1'] = $polarity_array['image_polarity1']` and for empty value  `$polarity_array['image_polarity1'] = "This slot is empty";` So you will need to write 9 conditions

Comment: Check my second example, that loops through the items. This is a php code, so you have to use: some html... <?php HERE THE CODE ?> ..other html html

Comment: When I insert a <?php tag, and then your loop, I get


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\web\view_build.php on line 171

And obviously I'm adding teh ?> at the end.

I have a lot of trouble incorporating echoes mid-way through my HTML documents. I always get errors

Comment: Post the whole code here or on pastebin, if told in comments like this ,it's impossible to give you any advice.

Comment: OK my bad, the line "if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i]) {" should be "if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i])) {"

Comment: If the code in the first post is what you now have, then you're - for change - missing a closing bracked ("}") for the "for" loop, after the if. Oh, and the bracket is not fixed...

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, the } is actually there.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\web\view_build.php on line 172

is my error. Line 172 is 

"    if(isset($polarity_array['image_polarity' . $i])) {    "

from your code.

Comment: "echo<<<_END" - there you are missing  a space before those <<<. But: To do it properly, why are you using heredoc in the first place? Just use: ?> and here you can have your html, with no problems <? here php again ?> html once more <?= $variable_to_echo ?> html something till the end of file -- isn't that easier way to do this? And correct one, too.

Comment: Success! You showed me a much better way to incorporate HTML into a document. I thought you always had to use HEREDOC.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're unsetting the `$key` from the `$array` you can use `foreach()` to show only the keys that now exist. At first I was thinking of using a `for` statement like @MightyPork suggested, but you have to know the total number of elements. This way you only use the existing elements.

```
foreach($polarity_array as $key=>$value){
     echo $key."=".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: That's good if he wants only the existing ones, though I think he wants them all, but a message "No mod in this slot" where the key is undefined. At least that's my understanding of the problem.

Comment: @MightPork the OP already has code in their example that says "No mod in this slot." If by using `unset()` they're basically creating more work for themselves then. I voted to close it, because it went from "what's wrong" to "fix my code dump."

Answer (score 0):

Calling `unset()` on an array element removes it, changing the length of an array. That's why you're getting 'underfined index' errors.

From [PHP Arrays Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

`unset($arr[5]); // This removes the element from the array`

Comment: They are associative arrays

Comment: `unset()` still removes the element, no?

Comment: yeah, but since it's associative, it doesn't look for array values but rather the associated key

key1 => value

it looks for key1, returns the value. it doesn't look for the first row.